# Which AudioEncoder codec is best for highest quality audio recording on android

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, media

I am recording both audio and video on my Xamarin.Forms project. Some people tell me that when they use it the audio quality is low when recording. 
After some research I think it has something to do with the encoder.

This is my line for setting the codec

```
 this.mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
```

[And here are the available encoder options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.audioencoder?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)

In some threads I see people recommend using AmrNb or Aac (which I already use). I tried all options and can't see any noticeable difference.

Which one is best for recording audio on smartphones?

Should I manually set audio bitrate, and if yes how do I determine it?

Comment: Use `Aac` is the best solution . Because it is  `High Efficiency AAC (HE-AAC) audio codec` .

Comment: You probably won't hear much difference if it is voice recordings. Also saying "Audio Quality is low", can mean a lot of different things. Can they be more specific? I.e. is the volume too low? Too much background noise? Is the audio distorted in some way? They are all really different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.mediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.VoiceRecognition);           
 this.mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
 this.mediaRecorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(16000);
```

I added these lines ( basically I increased the bitrate and changed audio source) and I think it's better now.